# Panel data clustering - how to assess the distance between individuals when the data are multivariate and longitudinal?

Tags: clustering, panel-data, distance, euclidean, dynamic-time-warping

I have an (unbalanced) panel dataset with 20 countries, 57 years, and 8 variables, and I would like to cluster the countries according to their dynamic trend in these variables (whether using kmeans or hierarchical clustering does not matter). 
I have seen this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88320/cluster-analysis-on-panel-data) and this [paper](https://francis-press.com/uploads/papers/FE1OcujsHtxSj0hVgyTyCeEvQFc4XBB4692KvjKO.pdf) which try to assess the issue but I would like to find a method based on a distance measure on which to implement the usual "cross-sectional" clustering algorithms.

In other words, I am looking for a dissimilarity measure to be applied to **multivariate** data, describing the diversity between the **shape** of individuals' **time trend** in the variables of interest.

Any suggestion on panel clustering in general are also welcome, thanks!